# Why is the Bondi-Van der Burg-Metzner-Sachs group often called only Bondi-Metzner-Sachs group?

Tags: relativity-theory

In general relativity, the Bondi-Van der Burg-Metzner-Sachs (BMS) group is the group of symmetries of future null infinity. To the best of my knowledge, it originated in the works of [Bondi, Van der Burg, and Metzner](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1962.0161) and later in the work of [Sachs](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1962.0206).

In spite of this, I have read multiple references that refer to this group as the Bondi-Metzner-Sachs group, ignoring Van der Burg. I'd say this is evident in the abbreviation BMS, instead of BVMS, for example. Furthermore, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bondi%E2%80%93Metzner%E2%80%93Sachs_group) calls the group the Bondi-Metzner-Sachs group.

Why is Van der Burg often ignored in the name of the BMS group? Isn't he one of the authors of the original paper?

Comment: It might be frustrating but we have many questions like this one and the answer is just simply: [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [paper by Bondi et al.](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1962.0161) is unusual in that different parts (A-D) are signed by different authors. Its history and context are thoroughly described in an (open access) [article by D. C. Robinson](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140/epjh/e2019-100020-1.pdf?pdf=core). Julian van der Burg, who was Bondi's PhD student, only signed Part B (together with Bondi), while Kenneth Metzner is the only signatory of Part C. Robinson states, though, that Bondi wrote the whole article. The super-translations of the BMS group appear only in Metzner's Part C and are then discussed in Part D, signed only by Bondi. Rainer (Ray) Sachs generalised these findings in a [subsequent publication](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1962.0206). Metzner was an American PhD student of Philip Morrison's at Cornell who joined the "collaboration" when Bondi was visiting during a sabbatical. Robinson quotes van der Burg with a statement from 2009 saying

> To this day I have no idea who Metzner is.

In summary, the acronym BMS seems chosen correctly, listing all authors who contributed to the concepts behind.